# Angular continua minha função antes da resposta do dialog

Tags: angular, typescript

Tenho uma função que chama um dialog caso for alterado o SKU de um produto, porém a função está sendo continuada antes do resultado do dialog.

Existe alguma forma de ficar aguardando pelo resultado e só depois continuar a função?

```
salvaAlteracoes(){
    for(let i=0;i<this.produtos.length;i++){
      if(this.produtos[i].id == this.produto.id){ //Quando encontrar na lista de produtos o id do produto que está alterando, verifica se o sku é diferente, se for, indica que foi alterado, então abre um dialog
        if(this.produtos[i].sku_prin != this.produto.sku_prin){
          const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogConfirmacaoSKU, { panelClass: 'dialogpanel' });
          dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
            if (result == false) {
              return;
          }
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

A função continua aqui, mas quando cai no if() ela não espera o evento afterClosed e continua a função. Como posso esperar?